# Swift compiler error after upgrading to El-Capitan

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, osx-elcapitan

I am working on a project developed in Swift. My project was working fine until I upgraded to **El-Capitan.** As I opened xcode project I am getting this error

> Opening import file for module 'Swift': Permission denied

I had refer similar questions on SO but it doesn't solve my problem. I am adding a sreenshot for more clarity[image]
Please can anyone provide the solution ? Any help would be appriciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: have you tried rebuilding permissions using Apple Disk Utility and/or a fresh install of Xcode ? Otherwise you could try to set the permissions to that file/those files manually so you could access them, if you're familiar with the terminal.

Comment: I tried reinstalling xcode, didn't work

Comment: You can try reseting Xcode preferences using this terminal command:

    defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, finally I got the answer. I recreated my project and copy all the code from the previous xcode project. The problem was compiler was not able to find the required file in the project location. I follow these steps.

1. Quit all projects and xcode completely.
2. Delete all derived data and dt.xcode from caches folder.
3. Create new xcode project in some different location.
4. copy all code from previous xcode.

hope this will help someone.